# Issues with Activeandroid and SQLCipher

Tags: android, sqlite, activeandroid

Hi I am developing android in which I want to do DB encryption. I am using Active-Android for sqlite DB. I tried to use ActiveAndroid-Secure `https://github.com/zsiegel/ActiveAndroid-Secure`. As This said I created compiled jar. And when I tried to include and run this project I shows me following error:

```
    Process: com.example.nileshkashid.secureactiveandroid, PID: 19057
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.activeandroid.DatabaseHelper
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:308)
at com.activeandroid.ModelInfo.scanForModelClasses(Unknown Source)
at com.activeandroid.ModelInfo.scanForModel(Unknown Source)
at com.activeandroid.ModelInfo.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.activeandroid.Cache.initialize(Unknown Source)
at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(Unknown Source)
at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(Unknown Source)
at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(Unknown Source)
at com.example.nileshkashid.secureactiveandroid.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:16)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1024)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4953)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1424)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5702)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
```

In my build.gradle file:

```
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/ActiveAndroid.jar')
   /* compile files('libs/sqlcipher.jar')
    compile files('libs/android.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-codec.jar')
    compile files('libs/guava-r09.jar')
    compile files('libs/native-libs-1.0.jar')*/

}
```

In my application class:

```
    package com.example.nileshkashid.secureactiveandroid;
import android.app.Application;
import com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid;
public class MainApplication extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ActiveAndroid.initialize(this);
    }
}
```

Is there anything I am missing. Need some help. Thank you.

Comment: Is any one with same issue?

Comment: I am with same issue. Any solution ?

Comment: Hi Suresh I solve this issue with these https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/  adding jars and `.so` files in my project. Let me know if you find any difficulty with adding these.

Comment: me too solved the issue in same same.

Comment: Any one required working library please let me know.

Comment: I have faced the same error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.activeandroid.DatabaseHelper", I have added the .so files in jniLibs within my main project but in build.gradle i have'nt done anything can you provide with the solution